# EF6 DB2 Select query filtering bug

Tags: c#, entity-framework, db2

I'am using EF 6.1.3 and EF DB2 6.1.0 for database. The problem is EF is not applying WHERE to my query. But if i copy the query from log it works how it should.

```
            int userId = int.Parse(User.Identity.Name);
            //Форматируем данные под таблицу
            var tasksQuery = context.Tasks
            .Where(t => t.AuthorId == 19)//HERE IS MY SIMPLE WHERE
            .Select(t => new
            {
                Id = t.Id,
                Author = t.Author.Client.LastName + " " + t.Author.Client.FirstName + " " + t.Author.Client.MiidleName,
                Title = t.Title,
                Type = t.Type.Id == TskTaskType.Types.Route ? t.Type.Name + "(" + t.Route.Name + ")" : t.Type.Name,
                Comment = t.Chains
                            .Where(chain => chain.ActionId != null && chain.ActionDate == t.Chains.Max(c => c.ActionDate))
                            .Select(chain => chain.Comment).FirstOrDefault(),//Комментарий последнего совершенного действия
                Status = t.Status.Name,
                StartDate = t.StartDate,
                EndDate = t.EndDate,
                AuthorId = t.AuthorId
            });


            var recordsTotal = tasksQuery.Count();
```

**First case(Wrong answer):**
[image]
    SQL(copying it to sql client gives correct count = "1"):[image]

**Second case(Correct, but i removed Author prop from projection. I need it, so it's not my solution):**
[image]
    SQL:[image]

**Third case(Correct, but userId is hardcoded. So it is not the solution also):**
[image]
SQL is the same as in first case, except it doesn't have any parameters like "@p__linq__0",it's value is hardcoded in the sql query.

Help me please, it seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my question.

It was a bug with DbCommand parameter types: if a parameter type is Decimal - Where statement is always true regardless of value. Tested it many times in many ways, Decimal parameter in this query allways breaks it. Very strange behaviour, in other parts of project everything works perfect with Decimal....

I've added **AuthorId** to my  Select projection and made it **Integer**. To check the result i've added CommandInterceptor to EntityFramework.

```
            int userId = int.Parse(User.Identity.Name);

            var tasksQuery = context.Tasks.Select(t => new
            {
                Id = t.Id,
                Author = t.Author.Client.LastName + " " + t.Author.Client.FirstName + " " + t.Author.Client.MiidleName,
                AuthorId = (int)t.AuthorId,//HERE IS TYPE CAST
                Title = t.Title,
                Type = t.Type.Id == TskTaskType.Types.Route ? t.Type.Name + "(" + t.Route.Name + ")" : t.Type.Name,
                Comment = t.Chains
                            .Where(chain => chain.ActionId != null && chain.ActionDate == t.Chains.Max(c => c.ActionDate))
                            .Select(chain => chain.Comment).FirstOrDefault(),
                Status = t.Status.Name,
                StartDate = t.StartDate,
                EndDate = t.EndDate
            }).Where(t => t.AuthorId == userId);//AND FILTERING AFTER CASTING TO INT


            var recordsTotal = tasksQuery.Count();
```

**Before changes(returns total count - INCORRECT):**[image]
**After changes(return filtered count - CORRECT):**[image]